# How to remove query string from url using javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I have one page when which have a query string like `http://www.test.com/mypage?abc=xyz`

I want only page URL after loading in browser, but my query string will not be removed.
e.g. `http://www.test.com/mypage`.

I need query string each and every time. I don't want to visualize to user.

Comment: I think there's no way for you to alter the browser query string without actually following the URL

Comment: Why did you tag this as C# while asking for JavaScript?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `POST` instead of `GET` to pass data between pages?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I've retagged the question as well now

Comment: No, you cannot change url in the address bar of the browser.

Comment: @Zruty but what if the OP actually means server side C# in ASP.NET page?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you still need to send the request with those query string, so I assume you are asking to hide it in the address bar. I suggest go with create a big 100% height/width iframe to link to your detail page and then user will not able to see the query string in the address bar directly as it's in the iframe

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is with a new HTML 5 feature on the history object:

```
window.history.replaceState(“Replace”, “Page Title”, “/mypage”);
```

Otherwise you'll need to use POST or reload the page with cookies to hide the query parameters.

Comment: That's a HTML5 feature. Chrome 5+, FF 4+, IE 10+.