# Update param and call action in controller on click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been banging my head over this for the past 3 days (No kidding!!!)....It seems like a very simple thing but I am just unable to do it. So I'm putting the question out here, and am open to any method which would work.

BACKGROUND : An advanced search form on submission used to generate an URL too large for the server. So the form had to be submitted via POST. So far, so good. Form submitted successfully, and the result was displayed. Only remaining problem was pagination.

As it's a POST call, it ruled out will pagination. While will-pagination merges param page to the existing params, but the problem is that it shows on url which results in the same error.

QUESTION: So is there any way, if the user clicks a link NEXT, I can

a) Update the page param

b) Keep the existing params

c) While not changing the URL

d) Transfer control back to the action in controller?

The only solution so far suggested was have a hidden form, repopulate it's value and submit again. The form's pretty complex, so if there is a cleaner way I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you want from your comment.  So editing my reply accordingly.  You want the information as to which column is being selected in the sort to be available to the controller without having that information available in the url string, and you want to use GET for this not POST

The challenge you have is that you want to preserve state between requests and you need a mechanism for doing this.  POST preserves that information by sending it in the body of the POST request.  GET does this by allowing you to populate the query string.  The other method for preserving state is to use a cookie.

You can manipulate the url with javascript on the page.  There are tutorials online for that.

But if you just want a simple controller hack as you say in your comment then the simplest one I can think of is to allow the user to make the GET request to the url with the query params in it, then handle this request in two steps - step one saves the query information to the cookie, step two redirects them to the url with that query string data stripped, and you look on the cookie to see if it has those fields before building your data for that page.  It's hacky but it works.

```
def sort
  session[:sort] = params[:sort]
  redirect_to url_without_the_query_string
end
```

There is also the new html 5 feature:

```
window.history.replaceState(“Replace”, “Page Title”, “/mypage”);
```

from this stackoverflow answer here: [How to remove query string from url using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716412/how-to-remove-query-string-from-url-using-javascript)

However I'm not sure I'd recommend messing with the url after load like that (I don't know enough about that solution so I'd recommend you read that answer and see if that fits).  So, if you MUST lose that data from the url string, because you need to somehow pass it between requests you either have to use POST, or use the session cookie/redirect method I describe above.

Comment: No, I definitely wasn't looking for this. My form method is POST. Form successfully sumbits. After this I get the set of results, with 50 entries on page, and columns which when clicked can be sorted. Now after the post form submission my url doesn't change. Till here, I'm happy & life is great. But when I click on the sortable links, or the will-paginated links, they merge params to my url instead of just saving them. So I was looking for a hack, in which within the controller, I can just strip the url of such parameters while I still have them accessible via params. Do I make sense?

Comment: I think so.  You want the user to be able to click on, say, a column heading.  This would normally add sort_column=foo to the query string in the url and then reload the page taking that params[sort_column] which is now set to foo in order to display the fields correctly.  However you don't want the ?sort_column=foo to show up. So your url would still be http://site_url/orders/advanced_search instead of http://site_url/orders/advanced_search?sort_column=foo

Comment: Yup, you got my problem perfectly. Now any luck with the answer? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot...Agree it's quite hacky so I'm actively looking for other solutions.

Comment: It's hacky but it's the only solution that does what you are asking in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does your html `<form>` have an `action` attribute? If not, add one that points to the page.

If you want to preserve the current GET params so that results from the POST can use , you will also need to modify the javascript triggered on the heading links so that as well as (or instead of) modifying the query string, they write the same data to hidden form fields (which of course then get posted in the body of the request). Your JS library may already include helpful functions for that.